# Download content button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a download button for html content in my page. Here is my project:

[image]

and I can drag to reorder planets like this:

[image]

How can I create a buttton to download current html content?

Update following code in App.js:

```
const getComponentsFromSearchQuery = (query) => {
  if (!query) return Object.values(planets);

  const filter = query.split(",").map((v) => v.trim());

  return (
    Object.entries(planets)
      .filter(([k]) => filter.some((f) => k.indexOf(f) !== -1))
      .map(([k, v]) => v)
  );
};

function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [generateClick, setGenerateClick] = useState(false);

  const [components, setComponents] = useState(
    getComponentsFromSearchQuery("")
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOnDragEnd = (result) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;

    const items = Array.from(components);
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);

    setComponents(items);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setComponents(getComponentsFromSearchQuery(searchQuery));
    setGenerateClick(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="planets">
          {(provided) => (
            <ul {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
              {components.map((C, index) => {
                return (
                  <Draggable key={C.name} draggableId={C.name} index={index}>
                    {(provided) => (
                      <li
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      >
                        <C />
                      </li>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </ul>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
```

How can I download the html content when I reorder the list of planets??

Comment: Just to be sure - after `handleOnDragEnd` is called you want to download HTML file containing whole markup of currently visible page, right?

Comment: after Dragend it will appear download button to download whole markup content

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help you. It takes too much time to setup code from scratch without full information about your project.

Comment: @fromaline Here is my little codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-forked-k2ie1?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing CodeSandbox. Probably the **easiest** way to do it with the current setup is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-forked-yosfe?file=/src/index.js). 
 It requires no adjustments to your existing code, but make sure the `ul` identifier (class in this example) is unique across the project. So maybe you should use an `id` instead.